# HttpProviderError when trying to send a tx with lower gasPrice

Tags: ethers.js, infura, gas-price

I am trying to send a tx to Ethereum mainnet with a lower gas price than the current gas price to have it in pending state until the gas price drops and it is picked up. I am using `ethers.js` for my client:

```
const gasPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits("5", "gwei");
const tx = await myContract.connect(myWallet).someAction({gasPrice: gasPrice});
console.log(tx);
```

When I execute this I am getting a `HttpProviderError`. Full stack trace below:

```
ProviderError: HttpProviderError
    at HttpProvider.request (/home/ethdev/workspace/my-project/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)
    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (/home/ethdev/workspace/my-project/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:187:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/home/ethdev/workspace/my-project/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

This is working when I either use the default gas price (by not specifying a custom gas price in the `Overrides` object) or when I specify a custom gas price that is higher than the gas price I can query from the provider via `ethers.provider.getGasPrice()`. So my assumption is that the RPC provider (which is Infura in my case) is rejecting any tx that has a gas price that is lower than the current gas price it is specifying.

My questions are:

- Is my assumption correct that the provider causes this error for the above described reasons, and if yes:

  - Is there any way around this issue other than switching the provider?
  - Is this behavior even configurable by the provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add a gas limit to the `Overrides` object. In that case, the transaction gets accepted:

```
const gasPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits("5", "gwei");
const tx = await myContract.connect(myWallet).someAction({gasPrice: gasPrice, gasLimit: 1000000});
console.log(tx);
```

Still, I am curious why this works when I override the gas price with a price that is equals to or higher than the one I can query from the provider and leave out the gas limit. It seems that the gas limit only needs to be specified when the specified gas price is lower than the current gas price.